# ASP.NET Core redirect http to https

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, redirect, asp.net-core

I have created a redirect rules in my web.config to redirect my website from http to https. The issue i have is that every single link on the website is now https. I have a lots of link to other website which don't have SSL and therefore i get certificate errors. This is what i have done:

```
  <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

How can i redirect https only for my domain and not every links on my website?

Comment: https://finalcodingtutorials.blogspot.ae/2017/03/non-www-to-www-with-http-to-https.html

Comment: This makes no sense. Rewrite only changes requests coming into the server. It doesn't change the html responses coming back from the server.

Answer (score 16):

Edit: While it still works, things changed a bit since I wrote this answer. Please check D.L.MAN's more up to date answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56800707/844207

In asp.net Core 2 you can use an URL Rewrite independent of the Web Server, by using
app.UseRewriter in Startup.Configure, like this:

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

            // todo: replace with app.UseHsts(); once the feature will be stable
            app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps(StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently, 443));
        }
```

Comment: The UseRewriter method comes from the following using statement:

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;

Answer (score 11):

Actually (ASP.NET Core 1.1) there is a [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting) named Rewrite that includes a rule for what you are trying to do.

You can use it on Startup.cs like this:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent();

app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Comment: here's some additional resource https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl

Comment: For Asp .Net Core 2.1 onwards, use `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` middleware.
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 11):

In ASP.NET Core 2.2 you should use **Startup.cs** settings for redirect http to https

so add this in **ConfigureServices**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.HttpsPort = 443;
    });                           // <=== Add this (AddHttpsRedirection) =====

    services.AddRazorPages();  
}
```

and add this in **Configure** :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();            // <=== Add this =====
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();    // <=== Add this =====
}
```

in **launchSettings.json** check blow items exsits:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:63278",
      "sslPort": 44377      // <<===  check this port exists.
    }
  },
  "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",  // <=== check https url exists.
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then enjoy it.

Answer (score 4):

asp.net core < 2 just put this code into your startup.cs

```
        // IHostingEnvironment (stored in _env) is injected into the Startup class.
        if (!_hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add also the following code in .net core 2.1

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

and the following part in service configuration

```
       services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
       {
        options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
        options.HttpsPort = 5001;
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET Core 2.1 just use this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();   // <-- Add this !!!!!
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection(); // <-- Add this !!!!!
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: relevant docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio