# How to create an HTTP module for IIS to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, for ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, httpmodule

I need to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS, and I need to do it in IIS layer, rather than in ASP.NET Core MVC.

I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319971/asp-net-core-redirect-http-to-https) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490426/iis-redirect-non-www-to-www-and-http-to-https) questions, and I also know about the [SSL middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl).

Yet I can't use rewrite module, and as I said, I need to do it in IIS layer.

The solution before ASP.NET Core was easy. I would create an HTTP module, register it in Web.Config and that was it.

Now since IIS's application pool is set to `No Managed Code` (which is recommended for performance issues) how can I create an HTTP Module?

Comment: Would IIS rewrite module help? Don't know if it works with .net core? Btw, why would you not use HTTP module, it's really ideal for the case?

Comment: Why can't you use the url rewriter module?

Comment: Why do you **have** to do it in IIS? Also, you don't **have** to use `No Managed Code`

Comment: @Kevin, it's because of a bigger architecture that relies on some part on IIS.

Comment: @MartinUllrich, Yeah we can do that, yet that's bad for performance. That might be our last choice. Before that I just wanted to see if it's possible to use old IIS features in ASP.NET Core MVC? And BTW, ANCM is itself an IIS Module.