# How to Redirect HTTP to HTTPs in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, .net-core, https

I want to redirect a HTTP request to HTTPS. How can I do in .Net Core 2.0?

I tried to add the below code in the `startup.cs` file but this is not working. Can any one help me for this?

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
    options.HttpsPort = 443;
});
```

Details about the code:

When I run my project first time, the `Configure()` and `AddHttpsRedirection()` gets called.

Then after I change https to http only after that it's not working means its not call any function from `stratup.cs`

I did this code and try to redirect to https, but page is just loading, it's not  redirecting, Even worse, I am not able to call `AddHttpsRedirection` function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core redirect http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319971/asp-net-core-redirect-http-to-https)

Comment: Check if you forget to add app.UseHttpsRedirection(); in your Configure-Method (Startup-Class)

Answer (score 0):

I have a .NET Core 2.1 project and I use the following:

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider services)
{
    ...
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    ...
}
```

Comment: i had also use this but i m not able do solve this issue